# Condition number of finite element stiffness matrix

Tags: finite-element, condition-number

In the FEM, there are certain applications in which the condition number $(\kappa)$ of the overall global stiffness matrix $(A)$ is computed or reduced by some preconditioner $(P)$. Are there any applications where the condition number of the tangent stiffness matrix for a single finite element (or some subregion) in the mesh would be useful?

Comment: I do research on preconditioning and numerical linear algebra, so my comment will be skewed towards that. Depending on the problem you are investigating, not the condition number itself but the bounds on eigenvalues and/or (generalized) Rayleigh quotients can be useful to develop/analyze preconditioners, and also analyzing the efficiency of the iterative solvers (sometimes). For example, see the proof of Lemma 4.3 in "Finite elements and fast iterative solvers". It is all based on eigenvalues of element mass matrices.